# can I develop a app for both iPhone 5 and iPhone 6 in same project without using auto layouts in xcode6?

Tags: ios

http://www.learnswift.io/blog/2014/6/12/size-classes-with-xcode-6-and-swift
How to use size classes,can you help me in understanding them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can just place a launchscreen of iphone 5(640*1136) for  iphone 6  so the same project you develop for iphone 5 that was working same in iphone 6. hope work for you . i did that in my project.

Comment: s i have it in my image.xcassets

Comment: ok open that , from left hand side  2 row to right have a launch screen file open that

Comment: open atribute inspector for launch sreen right hand side menu and select a device . and you just show many blocks in center page with different device name

Comment: ok now only you have to add a launch screen with asize of 640*1136 in both iphone 5 and iphone 6 than test it on iphone

Comment: what about remaining screens?

Comment: all block are required different size of launch screen based on device .

Comment: can you please help me to increase my  Reputation

Comment: how can i can do that,i am new to this site

Comment: there is a hidden check mark   with my ans click on it

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
However, using auto layout is strongly recommended.

I recommend that you should have to see [What's new in Interface Builder and Xcode videos of WWDC14](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/).

Comment: can i use separate xibs for two devices in same project one for iPhone 5 and another for iPhone 6?

Comment: Yes you can. You can programmatically choose initial view controller. You can initialize your view controller from the xib which you want. However using size classes and single XIB is recommended for XCode6 nature.

Comment: thanks jeeyul.can you suggest me any specific tutorials for auto layout and size classes?

Comment: As far as remember, ‘What's new in Interface Builder’ video says short overview for using size classes. What if you've developed using Xcode before, I think you don't have to need any other tutorial.